# Fatal error: Class 'BaseController' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm learning laravel4 from tutorials step by step .. but it gave me that error when trying to access `CategoriesController.php` although `BaseController.php` is there in controllers folder !!

that's `CategoriesController`

```
<?php 
class CategoriesController extends BaseController {
public function __construct(){
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf' , array('on'=>'post')) ;
 }
public function getIndex () {
    return View::make('categories.index')
    ->with('categories' , Category::all());
 }
public function postCreate(){
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all() , Category::$rules);
    if ($validator->passes()){
        $category = new Category ; 
        $category->name = Input::get('name');
        $category->save();
        return Redirect::to('admin/categories/index')
        ->with('message' , 'Category Created');
    }
    return Redirect::to('admin/categories/index')
    ->with('message', 'Something went wrong')
    ->withErrors($validator)
    ->withInput() ;
    }
public function postDestroy(){
        $category = Category::find(Input::get('id'));
        if($category){
            $category->delete() ;
            return Redirect::to('admin/categories/index')
            ->with('message' , 'Category Deleted');
        }
        return Redirect::to('admin/categories/index')
            ->with('message' , 'Something went wrong');    
     }
}
?>
```

The tree of my project app folder 
[image: tree]

Comment: where you are including CategoriesController.php file?

Comment: @punithasubramaniv in controllers folder .. in the same path with BaseController

Comment: When you say "when trying to access CategoriesController.php", how actually do you try to "access" it ?

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying `http://site/app/controller/CategoriesController.php` something like this right?

Comment: Was there a namespace in the BaseController file? There appears to be one in the latest version of Laravel for any that come across this.

Answer (score 0):

Try running **php artisan dump-autoload** and **composer dump-autoload** to regenerate the autoload files

Comment: i made a whole new project using composer but it gives me the same error !

Comment: tried running `artisan dump-autoload` and `composer dump-autoload` but nothing happened

Comment: Can you post the tree of your project app folder?

Comment: Hmm, Please can you post the code in the BaseController to pastie or something?

Answer (score 0):

This shoudn't be the issue but you never knows.. try this: `class CategoriesController extends \BaseController` notice the \ before BaseController

Answer (score 0):

You need to put "namespace" and "use Illuminate" **before the Class** and also **extends to "Controller"** NOT to "BaseController" , so try this:

```
<?php 

/*
* you need to put these 2 lines before your "Class" 
* //////////////////////////////////////////////////
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

class CategoriesController extends Controller {
     public function __construct(){
         $this->beforeFilter('csrf' , array('on'=>'post')) ;
     }
     ......
}
```

Hope it helps!